# What is the difference between an integer a and *(&a) ?

Tags: c, pointers

I am not getting the difference between an integer `a` and `*(&a)` ? I mean `*(&a)` returns the value contained in the address of `a` and it's the same as `a` , no? So why the use of pointers in this case?

Comment: Could you provide more context?

Comment: The only reason one could possibly write this is to prevent a from being stored exclusivley in a register (since it's address is taken, that is not possible).This has implications when the variable is used without initialization; it makes that less dangerous. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11965368/3150802.

Comment: Sure it is, it'll get optimized out.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the difference between an integer `a` and `*(&a)` ?

No difference. `int a;` declares `a` as a variable of an `int` type. `&a` is the address of `a` is of type `int *`, i.e. pointer type and therefore it can be dereferenced.   So, `*(&a)` will give the value of `a`.

Answer (score 2):

As long as `a` is a variable, there's no difference, they're identical.

However, if you use that expression in a macro for instance, it will fail with a compiler error for temporary objects (`*&(x+1)`) or literals (`*&5`). Perhaps there's a reason for making that distinction in code.

Comment: *Perhaps there's a reason for making that distinction in code*: What's that?

Comment: @haccks If the macro evaluates the expression twice you want to prevent it from being used on something that may have side effects.

Comment: @haccks, I have no idea, but I've seen lots of weird little quirks people use in their libraries. Boost is enough to make your teeth hurt. Besides, this is the only use I can think of for the construct in question.

Answer (score 0):

Take this as an example,

```
int a = 1;
int *ptr = &a;
```

`ptr` points to some address in memory, and the address of `ptr` itself, is different in memory.

---

Now, take a look at below drawing,

```
// *ptr = *(&a) 
// Get the adress of `a` and dereference that address.
// So, it gives the value stored at `a`

memory address of        a -> 0x7FFF1234
value stored at          0x7FFF1234 = 1

memory address of        ptr -> 0x7FFF4321
value stored at          0x7FFF4321 = &a = 0x7FFF1234

                                           +-------+
           +------------>  0x7FFF1234 ---->|a = 1  |
           |                               +-------+
           |              +-----------------+ 
           |              | ptr =           |    
           +--*ptr<-------| 0x7FFF1234 [&a] |<--- 0x7FFF4321       
                          +-----------------+
```

So, there is **no difference** between both of them, i.e., `int a` and `*(&a)` are same.

Answer (score 0):

More to the point, you wouldn't normally write `*(&a)`, or `*&a`.  This could arise as a result of macros or something, but you would normally never actually write something like that explicitly.  You can take it to extremes:  `*&*&*&*&*&*&a` works just as well.  You can try it for yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int     a = 123;
    int     b = *&*&*&*&*&*&a;

    printf("%d\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```